# Convert Minutes to Years, months, days, hours, minutes in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I get an int with a large amount of minutes, for example:

```
int minutes = 1000000
```

And I want to convert it into a string with a format that contains: Years, Months, Days, Hours and Minutes.

Something like this:

(**the following string example does not correspond to 1,000,000 min**, its just to see the format)

```
String time = '3 years, 2 month, 21 days, 13 hours, and 45 minutes'
```

I've been looking if I could solve it with `Duration` but it doesn't allow months or years. I have also tried comparing `DateTimes` but I can't find a suitable answer.

Comment: The only way is to do it with `Duration` and convert manually between days-months and days-years.

Comment: What you want is not really possible since the size of month and year are dependent on the day you are start counting from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, working with dates times can be hard. A naive solution would be to add your duration to a "zero" `DateTime` and using `DateTime.minute` etc to get the values: e.g.

```dart
const minutes = 100000;
final duration = Duration(minutes: minutes);
final zero = DateTime();

final dateTime = zero.add(duration);

// then you can use:
dateTime.minute  // will be between 0 and 59
dateTime.hour  // will be between 0 and 23
```

Be careful, `day` and `month` begin at 1, not 0.

However, this simply adds `minutes` * 60 seconds to `dateTime`, which may or may not be what you want. You should consider, for example, whether a year is equal to 365 days exactly, or whether you are taking into account leap years (or leap seconds for that matter), what timezone are you evaluating this in, etc.

If you are happy with the definition that: "a year is 12 months", "a month is 30 days", etc, then you might prefer a more manual solution:

```dart
const timeInMinutes = 1000000;

final minutes = timeInMinutes % 60;
final hours = ((timeInMinutes - minutes) / 60) % 24;
// etc
```

Alternatively, check out the `duration` package on pub.dev: https://pub.dev/packages/duration
It seems to do something similar to what you want

Comment: Both solutions have been useful for my case. A small detail in case you want to correct it from your answer: day and month begin at 1 instead of day and year. Thank You!

Comment: upvoted. thank you so much, got idea from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use below method to get formatted Yers:Month:Days:Hours:Min.

You can skip anyone of them if you want like
Days:Hour:Min and Hours:Min and so on.

```
static differenceFormattedString(int minute){
try{

  DateTime now = DateTime.now();

  Duration difference = Duration(minutes: minute);

  final today = DateTime(now.year).add(difference).subtract(const Duration(days: 1));

  return '${today.day} Days ${today.hour} Hours ${today.minute} Min';

}catch(e){
  return '';
}
```

}

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
String getRemainingTime(DateTime orderDate) {
  var currentDateTime = DateTime.now();
  var duration = (orderDate.difference(currentDateTime).inMinutes) + 1440;
  int days = duration ~/ 1440;
  int hours;
  duration = duration - (1440 * days);
  hours = duration ~/ 60;
  duration = duration - (60 * hours);

  String dateString;
  if (days == 0) {
    dateString = '$hours hrs $duration mins';
  } else {
    dateString = '$days days $hours hrs $duration mins';
  }

  return dateString;
}
```